# How to use like with a specific pattern?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to check if a field in a specific table contains also number that have as pattern `number - number`, in particular I have a record that have the field name which contains this value: `Besëlidhja Lezhë vs. Tërbuni Pukë 1 - 1`,

so I'm trying to get also all the rows of that table that contains a number inside the field name. I tried:
   `SELECT * FROM venue WHERE name REGEXP '[0-9]'`

but this will return an empty result, any idea?

Comment: http://thingsilearn.wordpress.com/2008/02/28/mysql-query-speed-regexp-vs-like/   This link explains why using LIKE is more efficient that RegEXP. This might be an option for you. You could use:              SELECT * FROM venue WHERE name LIKE '%0-9%'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just extend your pattern:

```
SELECT *
FROM venue
WHERE name REGEXP '[0-9] [-] [0-9]'
```

However, your name has a number (based on what the characters appear to be), so your `where` clause should work as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this reg exp for your case `\d\s\-\s\d`

```
SELECT *
FROM venue
WHERE name REGEXP '\\d\\s\\-\\s\\d'
```

Comment: This won't work you need to use double slashes.. it's in the manual "Because MySQL uses the C escape syntax in strings (for example, \n to represent the newline character), you must double any \ that you use in your REGEXP arguments. "

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thank you for comment. I've added double slashes to rex exp